# How to display text only in the collapsable navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Navbar** how it should be:

[image: Navbar how it should be]

I want the text *idealize*, *develop*, *prototype* and *about* to appear next to the icons **only** in the collapsable navbar. The text appears on larger viewport sizes, too, what I **don't want**:

[image: Navbar how it not should be]

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">        
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#">
            <img src="images/avezlogo.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li id="orange"><a href="#idealize">
                    <img src="images/bulb.png"><span class="collapse">idealize</span>
                </a></li>
                <li id="cyan"><a href="#develop">
                    <img src="images/laptop.png"><span class="tittle">develop</span>
                </a></li>
                <li id="purple"><a href="#prototype">
                    <img src="images/printer.png"><span class="tittle">prototype</span>
                </a></li>
                <li id="red" class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#about">
                    <img src="images/dots.png" id="dots"><span class="tittle">about</span>                        
                </a>                        
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>    
</nav>
```

Sorry about any noob mistakes on my code. I'm new to Bootstrap and web design. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: none;` inside of a media query to target and hide your images at the mobile breakpoint. See example.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#">
        <img src="images/avezlogo.png">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li id="orange">
            <a href="#idealize">
              <img src="images/bulb.png"><span class="collapse"> idealize</span>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li id="cyan">
            <a href="#develop">
              <img src="images/laptop.png"><span class="tittle"> develop</span>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li id="purple">
            <a href="#prototype">
              <img src="images/printer.png"><span class="tittle"> prototype</span>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li id="red" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#about">
              <img src="images/dots.png" id="dots"><span class="tittle"> about</span> 
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it should behave. Links should be seen in all viewport sizes. If you only want to see the links in the *collapsable navbar* and not in the *not-collapsable navbar*, you can do this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #myNavbar .navbar-right {
        display: none;
}
```

But then you see in larger viewport sizes a blank navbar without a toggle icon on the right side. And that's not what you want, I think.

If you want a collapsable navbar all the time, the best solution would be to customize the Bootstrap CSS here:

[Bootstrap customize grid](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=613e4e2240b9c556e6dd#grid-system)

and set the `@grid-float-breakpoint` to a large width, e.g. 3000px. Download and compile and the CSS should do it.

Answer (score 0):

the media query worked fine. Thanks a lot. I was also wondering. Why doesn't the dropdown menu in the first image close after clicking one of the links? I have to click the menu button again for it to close. How could I change this? Thanks again.